# updated the request on liquibase, but the error still did not change

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

```
self-backend-container  | Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`finalproject`.`t_users_permissions`, CONSTRAINT `FK_t_users_permissions_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `t_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) [Failed SQL: (1452) INSERT INTO t_users_permissions (users_id, permissions_id)
self-backend-container  | VALUES
self-backend-container  |     (2, 1),
self-backend-container  |     (3, 1),
self-backend-container  |     (4, 1),
self-backend-container  |     (1, 2)]
self-backend-container  |       at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:447) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:78) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:161) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1270) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1252) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:679) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       ... 64 common frames omitted
self-backend-container  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`finalproject`.`t_users_permissions`, CONSTRAINT `FK_t_users_permissions_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `t_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
self-backend-container  |       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-backend-container  |       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-backend-container  |       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-backend-container  |       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-backend-container  |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:443) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-backend-container  |       ... 69 common frames omitted
```

````
    CREATE TABLE t_users (
                             id bigint auto_increment,
                             email varchar(255),
                             full_name varchar(255),
                             password varchar(255),
                             primary key (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE t_permission (
                                  id bigint auto_increment,
                                  role varchar(255),
                                  primary key (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE t_users_permissions (
     users_id bigint,
     permission_id bigint
    );

    -- Add foreign key constraint for t_users_permissions -> t_users
    ALTER TABLE t_users_permissions
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_t_users_permissions_user_id
            FOREIGN KEY (users_id)
                REFERENCES t_users(id)
                    ON DELETE CASCADE;

    ALTER TABLE t_users_permissions
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_t_users_permissions_permission_id
            FOREIGN KEY (permission_id)
                REFERENCES t_permission(id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE;```



INSERT INTO t_users (email, full_name, password)
VALUES
    ('takhirjon22@mail.ru', 'Takhirzhan', '$2a$12$NVozRfXN.NtAHw6dcZQhk.ebUT3w3ghJkrdcdgOb.beBVMmk.hiY.'),
    ('amina_b@gmail.com', 'Amina', '$2a$12$Ni8jBquyFP/aLd4rQzEGrOobiE0REtxxonGkWNYNaGN45a9zUp3J2'),
    ('alexteacheredu02@gmail.com', 'Alex', '$2a$12$Ni8jBquyFP/aLd4rQzEGrOobiE0REtxxonGkWNYNaGN45a9zUp3J2'),
    ('kazybektalgat15@gmail.com', 'Kazybek', '$2a$12$f.9GUmwRvkXBOPmji6H8YOTrgY29QBbbLd.8VW6weku3DJ1./FVFK');

INSERT INTO t_permission (role)
VALUES
    ('ROLE_USER'),
    ('ROLE_ADMIN');

INSERT INTO t_users_permissions (users_id, permission_id)
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 1);
````

I have updated everything im my migration but for some reaon it gives me old issues. I'm building prohect on SPringBoot and trying to use docker-compoose.yml